# Is there any function for checking the string parameter contains only numbers or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, function

I need to create a function that will get parameters as string and check if that string param contains only numbers or not. I tried doing this but I m not sure of the REGEX value.

```js
function validateNum(x) {
  var regex = /^\d+$/

  var isValid = regex.test(x.value);
  if (isValid) {
    console.log("This is a Number. Thus, Accepted!.");
  } else {
    console.log("Only Numbers allowed.");
  }
  return isValid;
}
console.log(validateNum("12x3aj")) //Only Numbers allowed.
console.log(validateNum("12345")) //This is a Number. Thus, Accepted!.
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Strings don't have a `value` property. Just use `regex.test(x)`

Answer (score -1):

Seems you wanna something like `Array.from(myString).every(Number.isInteger)`.